# Tiling rectangles using all squares of sides 1, 2, 3, ..., n

Tags: co.combinatorics, tiling

Do integers *n* greater than 2 exist such that all the squares of sides 1, 2, 3, ..., *n* can be partitioned into two or more sets (none a singleton) each of whose squares can be used to tile a rectangle?

Comment: A few questions:

1) Are we allowed to use multiple copies of a square when tiling a respective rectangle?

2) As formulated now, there is a trivial partition into $n$ singleton sets, with each square tiling a rectangle = itself. Should there be additional restrictions, like none of the tiled rectangles can be a square, or the partition should be non-trivial?

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov I have clarified the second issue. The answer to the first is no, no multiple copies of each square.